# Clearing HTML5 Canvas performance for mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm having some big problems with HTML5 canvas as my app draws a LOT of shapes on several layers (using KineticJS) and then I need to clear the canvas/all layers in order to redraw a load of different shapes.

This is fine in the brower on a desktop, however mobile browsers crash after a few iterations of clearing/redrawing the canvas I'm assuming due to the canvas load. At the moment I'm removing each layer from the stage and creating new ones to clear/redraw, but maybe clearing every shape of each layer would give better performance?

Can someone point me in the right direction of the best way to clear/redraw so that the performance is reasonable on a mobile?

Thanks,
Becky

Comment: Do you have a test site where I can go see your page in my mobile browser? Also, mobile browsers are picky, if you try running on iPhone iOS, it might not even show, similarly with latest Chrome browser for Android. The best canvas compatibility I've gotten was Firefox for Android and surprisingly Safari for iPad 2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I haven't got a test site I can send you to unfortunately, but the canvas itself its behaving as it should on all devices I've tried (same as desktop I mean) its purely the crashing after a few reloads that is different.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when is crashes? If you're on iOS you can connect your phone to desktop Safari and debug.

Comment: How you clear layers? May be problem in memleaks.